# What is "list_display_links" for Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, hyperlink, django-admin, changelist

I have **`Person` model** below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    age =  models.IntegerField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

Then, I assigned `"first_name"`, `"last_name"` and `"age"` to [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) in **`Person` admin** as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("first_name", "last_name", "age") # Here
```

Now, **FIRST NAME**, **LAST NAME** and **AGE** are displayed as shown below:

[image]

Next, I assigned `"first_name"`, `"last_name"` and `"age"` to [list_display_links](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display_links) in **`Person` admin** as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("first_name", "last_name", "age")
    list_display_links = ("first_name", "last_name", "age") # Here
```

But, nothing happened to **the "change list" page** as shown below:

[image]

So, what is `list_display_links`?

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the values of **LAST NAME** and **AGE** become the links to **the "change" page** in addition to the values of **FIRST NAME** as shown below. *By default, the values of **the first column "FIRST NAME" displayed** are the links to **the "change" page**:

[image]

So, you can go to **the "change" page** by clicking on **Smith** as shown below:

[image]

The documentation explains about [list_display_links](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display_links) below:

> Use list_display_links to control if and which fields in list_display
> should be linked to the "change" page for an object.
>
> By default, the change list page will link the first column – the
> first field specified in list_display ...